# Move icons to bottom of launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, 16.10, appearance, workspace-switcher

Is there any way to move an icon to the bottom of the launcher near the Trash? I'm looking to move the Workspace Switcher and Show Desktop icons down there and not have them grouped with my applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot configure items to be at the bottom of the launcher, no. The separation is part of the design, and implemented in the code directly without a configuration option.

Comment: Well, I can!  Left click the Workspace switcher and hold the left click.  Now, slide it down to the bottom next to the trash icon.

Comment: @ThomasByers Well, no, you can't. Sure, if you have enough icons on the launcher, the position of the workspace switcher and drive icons will be near the trash can. However, you cannot force it always be at the bottom near the trash, as requested in this question.